Problem with mySQL . Can't open my localhost php .How to solve this?
When i click Start for MySQL, shows this error.
In my folder htdocs display file aria_log.00000001 .
How to solve this?
After Deleting the aria_log. Shut down xampp, then start again and the same error is here over and over again.


How is this problem related to PHP?


Elena, As You Mention Xampp Show Error aria_log.00000001 files.

So, i have temporary solution for this right now is as below.

First Of All You have to  End Task - Xampp - Control Panel & Mysql From Task Manager Window.
For Windows User :  You Can Use  Ctrl + Alt + Del Key To Open Task Manager.

Now, Afte End Task the Xampp Server - go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory

Delete the ibdata1 File and Remove all the Files which names start with - aria_log.######## file

Now, After Delete that files Restart Xampp App & mysql Server.



NOTE: In Other Hand, if this solution not works for you, I would like to Suggest you to Reinstall Latest Xampp Version Which compatible according  to your os and Platform of x32 or x64 bit.

